# Printing first 100 prime numbers to a file

Tags: c++

I have to write out a list of prime numbers from 1-100, using a function we have previously wrote, to a file. The commented out part isn't anything related; it's just the previous code we used for the function. I don't know exactly what's going on because the file isn't even being created, and the part inside the for loop is executing with just 2's, 100 times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main () {

ofstream outputFile;
int p = 2;

cout << "I will be giving you the first 100 prime numbers " << endl;
cout << "And giving you a file containing those numbers." << endl;

outputFile.open("PrimeNumbers100.txt");

        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) 
        {

            isPrime(p);
            cout << p << endl;
            outputFile << p << endl;

        }

outputFile.close();
cout << "You should now have the file." << endl;

/* int n;
int counter = 0;
int p = 2;

cout << "Welcome to prime counter. " << endl;
cout << "Which prime number would you like? ";
cin >> n;

while (counter < n) {
        if (isPrime(p)) {
        counter++;
    }
    p++;
}
p = p - 1;
cout << "Prime number " << n << " is " << p << "." << endl;
*/

return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int p) {

bool result = true;

if (p < 2) {
    result = false;
}
else {
    int stop = (int) (sqrt(p + .5));
    for (int d = 2; d <= stop; d++) {
        if (p % d == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong here, and why it isn't even creating the file?

Comment: You should check that `outputFile.is_open()` is true.  if it is then the file is being created and you just can't find it.

Comment: Is this a question about calculating prime numbers, or writing to a file? Either could be a good SO question, but not both.

Comment: *"The commented out part isn't anything related;"* Then why did you include it in your question?

Comment: The part you commented out is much closer to a solution than the code you're using. You only need to add one line to the loop.

Comment: You call `isPrime` only to ignore the result. Also, add error checking to as many of your operations as you can, particularly opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `p` at the top with `2`. You should be calling `isPrime` with `i` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `2`s because you're printing out and storing `p`, but the loop is going over `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. Upon research I did find where it was saving the files, and there are instances of it just not working at all. However, This code runs and does give me everything I need it to.. Thank you for the tips, and I appreciate the very.... constructive feedback.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main () {

ofstream outputFile;

cout << "I will be giving you the first 100 prime numbers " << endl;
cout << "And giving you a file containing those numbers." << endl;

outputFile.open("PrimeNumbers100.txt");


        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) 
        {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
            outputFile << i << endl;
            }

        }

outputFile.close();
cout << "You should now have the file." << endl;

return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int p) {

bool result = true;

if (p < 2) {
    result = false;
}
else {
    int stop = (int) (sqrt(p + .5));
    for (int d = 2; d <= stop; d++) {
        if (p % d == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

return result;
}
```